# Isolate typescript build/compile on each project in a monorepo?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, monorepo

Currently have a **angular app** and a **express server** inside one repo. My problem is if whenever i change a file on my angular app, it also re-compiles the **express server files**.

My expected behaviour is the **angular app** only re-compiles when its file changes and it doesn't re-compile the express server, same goes with the **express server**.

I think it has something to do with configuration.

Here's my folder structure:

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── server/ <- express app
│   └── package.json
├── client/ <- angular app
│   ├── src/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── models/
    └── user.model.ts <- interface model shared between client and server
```

Here's the angular app's `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["../models/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    // "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Here's the express app's `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["./models/*"]
    },
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./server",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules/"]
}
```

Is there something i should change in my config?
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: moving tsconfig.json to server does not solve the problem?

Comment: @MihályiZoltán it doesn't work. I'm having errors specificially with the `csurf` npm package because it is exported using `export = csurf` instead of `export default` . even if i use `esModuleInterop` in tsconfig

Comment: Is the angular module which throws this error?

Comment: nope. when moving tsconfig.json to server, that's the only time it shows an error and it is related to a npm package.

It has no error in angular

Comment: I have no idea, what causes that. But does it solve the original problem?

Comment: nope. i can't run the server because of the error.